# Remove a class and then add a class to the next item in a rundown when clicking a button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a rundown when a user clicks on a button, it removes a class from one item in the list and then add the class to the next item in the list.

Example:

```
<button id="next-item">next item</button> //button to advance
<div class="nav-right"> //list of items to rundown
  <div class="irl-today-item current">item 1</div>  //first item
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 4</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 5</div>
</div>
```

I got it working by adding the class `current` to the next item but it doesn't remove `current` from the previous item.

Code:

```
$(function(){
$("#next-item").on("click", function(){
   $('.nav-right').removeClass('.current');
   $('.nav-right').find('.current').next().addClass('current');
})
```

I'm looking for a way to remove `current` from the last item when advancing.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/ya73eovp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Your remove class method is not working.
Second, You have to add the class first and then remove the current element or get the element into memory.

Check the below code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#next-item").on("click", function(){
       var curr = $('.nav-right').find('.current');
       if(curr.next().length > 0) { // If you want to stop at last element
           curr.next().addClass('current');
           curr.removeClass('current');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: `var curr = $(...` don't need `$(curr)` can just be `curr.next()...` etc

Comment: Yes, we can just put like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#next-item").on("click", function(){
      var ari = $('.nav-right .current').index();      
       $('.nav-right').find('.current').removeClass('current');
        ari++;
        $('.nav-right .irl-today-item').eq(ari)
.addClass("current");});
});
```

```css
.current {border-left:5px solid green}
.irl-today-item {padding:5px 10px}
.next_slide {border-left:5px solid blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-item">next item</button>
<div class="nav-right">
  <div class="irl-today-item current">item 1</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 4</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 5</div>
</div>
```