# How to unwrap a div and then add a div to the next item in a list on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question earlier ([Remove a class and then add a class to the next item in a rundown when clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302102/remove-a-class-and-then-add-a-class-to-the-next-item-in-a-rundown-when-clicking)) and while that one works, I asked the wrong type of question. Inside of removing and adding a class, I'm trying to wrap and unwrap a div inside another div and wrap a div inside the next item on a click.

What I'm trying to do is remove the div wrapping of `.current` around item 1 and wrap a div called `.current` on the next item in the rundown (item 2).

My code:

```js
(function() {
  $("#next-item").on("click", function() {
    var curr = $('.nav-right').children('.current'); //find .current
    if (curr.next().length > 0) { // If you want to stop at last element
      curr.next().wrapInner('current'); //wrap a div around next item
      curr.contents().unwrap(); //unwrap div from previous item
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.current {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--button to advance-->
<button id="next-item">next item</button>
<!--list of items to rundown-->
<div class="nav-right">
  <!--first item-->
  <div class="irl-today-item">
    <div class="current">item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 4</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 5</div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/wzt6bp0d/

Comment: Please do check the below link. I have updated the answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/a319fsoq/9/

Comment: Is there unique content or something about `.current` and `.current2` other than style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial selector for finding the current item was incorrect (if it were a `find()` instead of `children()` it would have ended up matching the `.current` div itself, rather than the parent element you wanted; with `children()` it matches nothing, because `.current` is not a direct child of `.nav-right`.)

Your `wrapInner` was also incorrect; you need to pass the full DOM element, not just a class name.

```js
$("#next-item").on("click", function() {
  var curr = $('.nav-right .current').parent(); //find .current's parent
  if (curr.next().length > 0) { 
    curr.children('.current').contents().unwrap(); // remove .current
    curr.next().wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>'); // add it to the next element
  }
});
```

```css
.current {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-item">next item</button>
<!--button to advance-->
<div class="nav-right">
  <!--list of items to rundown-->
  <div class="irl-today-item">
    <div class="current">item 1</div>
  </div>
  <!--first item-->
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 4</div>
  <div class="irl-today-item">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below gives the onclick an ability to loop, even from the beginning when it reaches the end:

```
$(function(){

    // store all items 
    var allItems =  $(".nav-right").children();

    // initialize for loop counter
    var i = 0;

    // onclick
    $("#next-item").on("click", function(){

       // select the current item 
       var wrapper = document.querySelector('.current');

       // removing the current wrapper 
       wrapper.outerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;

       // looping and wrap the next item with current div
       i = (i + 1) % allItems.length;
       allItems.eq(i).wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>');
    });


});
```

Updated as per suggestion of @daniel-beck:

```
$(function(){

    // store all items 
    var allItems =  $(".nav-right").children();

    // initialize for loop counter
    var i = 0;

    // onclick
    $("#next-item").on("click", function(){

       // select the current item and remove the current wrapper 
       $('.current').contents().unwrap();

       // looping and wrap the next item with current div
       i = (i + 1) % allItems.length;
       allItems.eq(i).wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>');
    });


});
```

Comment: Writing directly to outerHTML has the side effect of destroying any event bindings or form input values in the content being overwritten, which may not be desirable.   jQuery's `.unwrap()` would probably be a better choice here.